# how do I get consistent execution times?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, time, raspberry-pi

I am preparing for a coding challenge, where the fastest calculation of pi to the 10000th digit wins. all calculations will be run on a raspberry Pi4 running linux during competition.
I want to know which code runs the fastest, so I can know which function to submit.

so I wrote a little program named "lol" to try and establish a baseline around a known time.

```
//lol....lol is an exe which calls usleep()
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    usleep(100);
    return 0;
}
```

then to measure execution time, I wrote this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    //returns runtime in nanoseconds
    //useage: runtime <program>
    //caveates: I put the exe in /home/$USER/bin
    //start timing
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    //executable being  timed:
    system(argv[1]);
    // After function call
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(stop - start);
    cout << argv[1] << " " << duration.count() << endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

my issue is that the run time seems to be wildly variant. Is this because I'm running in userspace and my system is also doing other things? why am I not getting more consistent run times?

```
$ ./run_time lol
lol 13497886
$ ./run_time lol
lol 11175649
$ ./run_time lol
lol 3340143
./run_time lol
lol 3364727
$ ./run_time lol
lol 3372376
$ ./run_time lol
lol 1981566
$ ./run_time lol
lol 3385961
```

Comment: You're also measuring the overhead of `system` – including the time it takes to locate the executable in `$PATH`– which is not insignificant. You would get a fairer measure with `fork`/`exec`.

Comment: You appear to have rewritten the Linux `time` command. Is that not available on the PI?

Comment: Timing `usleep` will be measuring clock ticks, not microseconds.  Clock ticks are much more granular.

Comment: Without deeper knowledge... AFAIK, the computation of Pi with 10000 digits may be that time-consuming that a few micro (or even milli) seconds difference can be considered as noise. IMHO it's the algorithm to compute Pi where you decide about win or lose. Did you already try anything? How long does it run so far?

Comment: @Galik it is available, but I didnt see and setting for nanoseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. instead of executing a program, measure a function completion in a single program:

```
    
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    //function being  timed:
    my_func();
    // After function call
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
```

you are using `chrono` header. so why `usleep`when you can use `sleep_for`:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

The merits of this contest is not how you micro-optimize to save `1ns`. It`s about choosing the right algorithm to calculate pi.

Comment: youre not wrong, but I'm having to conform to how the competition will be run, and theyre not going to be integrating all the code they get into functions. the fork /exec, is probably the faster way to execute, then again, I only need to optimize my function, the rest is really out of my control. ok, i'm convinced answer accepted.